# jQuery/Ajax - selector don't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I use jQuery.ajax() to load HTML content from some PHP into an element on the page, jQuery selectors don't work on elements in that loaded HTML.

Is this a common problem or do I have to put together an example?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="../jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="htmlcontent">
        <a href="#">Blah</a><br />
        <a href="#">Bleh</a><br />
    </div>
    <div id="replacecontent">
        <br /><a href="#">Replace content</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#htmlcontent a").click(function() {
            alert("Clicked on a link!");
        });
        $("#replacecontent a").click(function() {
            $("#htmlcontent").html('<a href="#">This doesn't alert(). Why?</a>');
        });         
    </script>
</body>
```

Ok, that wasn't too hard. :)

Comment: *"do I have to put together an example"* : Yes

Comment: You're going to have to show us the code, because I've created html on a page in a .ajax callback and then selected it later.

Comment: It's always best to show an example. However, if the elements are in the DOM, then jQuery selectors should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure your selectors are just fine.  It's probably the event handlers that aren't bound right.  are you using .bind() or .click()?  A common problem is that you can't use those standard events to bind to from elements that don't exist yet on the page.  You may want to look into [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), which attaches a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now **and in the future**.

So try this:

```
    $("#htmlcontent a").live('click', function() {
        alert("Clicked on a link!");
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Selectors don't work after you have modified your DOM, because the elements they were attached to will be manipulated or removed. If you want to bypass this, you would have to use [`$.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`$.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

This is the explanation for the `.live()` event attachment:

> The .live() method is able to affect
>   elements that have not yet been added
>   to the DOM through the use of event
>   delegation: a handler bound to an
>   ancestor element is responsible for
>   events that are triggered on its
>   descendants. The handler passed to
>   .live() is never bound to an element;
>   instead, .live() binds a special
>   handler to the root of the DOM tree.

Answer (score 2):

The elements you're trying to select are not present in the DOM at the time the `click()` events are bound.

Have a look at [jQuery.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/): *Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.*

```
    $("#replacecontent").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        $("#htmlcontent").html('<a href="#">This will work now alert(). Why?</a>');
    });
```

I prefer `.delegate()` over `.live()` since it's more efficient, giving us an easy way to specify a context for the selector. With `.live()`, every single click on the entire document has to be compared to the specified selector, with `.delegate()` just elements in the `$("#replacecontent")` container.